# Will my passport get stamped? Flying JFK>SVO>MAD

Tags: customs-and-immigration, europe, russia, svo

Will my passport get stamped in Moscow even though it is a connecting flight? will i have to go through immigration or passport control?

Comment: All on a single ticket, or did you book two different tickets?

Comment: That's an odd routing. New York to Madrid via Moscow? Was it cheap, at least?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Right now Aeroflot is a lot cheaper then most airlines for quite a few destinations.

Comment: Well, if it's on a single booking then the usual rules apply. You'll get to see where Edward Snowden spent a month, but you won't get to see Russian immigration.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed.  It seems to me to be perfectly clear and answerable.  I'm also a bit dismayed that not one of the five close voters left a comment with any explanation.

Comment: @NateEldredge It's missing 1 crucial piece: citizenship.

Comment: Even more crucial piece: whether it's a single ticket, or whether they have to collect luggage and check in again.

Comment: @Karlson, in Russia, the necessity to go through immigration does not depend on nationality. There are other pieces of information that are lacking, though.